# how to put the data on the map from database

Tags: javascript, json, php, mapbox-gl-js

I wanted to display a polygon with the coordinated on my map and each time i click the button.

This is my database:

[image]

I get the data from the database with php

```
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM waypoint";

        $server = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $db = "scandrone";  
        $conn = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $db);

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        $json_array = array();

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $json_array[] = $row;
        }


        echo json_encode($json_array);


?>
```

I am made an load function, i created an variable to stock my JSON data and i tested to see if it works by doing this "myJsArray[0].longitude, myJsArray[0].latitude" and it works but i have add it one by one but instead of that i want to add everything at once.

```
var myJsArray = <?php echo json_encode($json_array); ?>;


map.on('load', function() {
var calcButton = document.getElementById('anim');
calcButton.onclick = function() {

map.loadImage('./images/index.jgp',
    function(error, image) {
    if (error) throw error;
    map.addImage('marker', image);
        }
    );

map.addSource('france', {
'type': 'geojson',
'data': {
'type': 'Feature',
'geometry': {
'type': 'Polygon',
'coordinates': [
                [   
                    [myJsArray[0].longitude, myJsArray[0].latitude],
                    [myJsArray[2].longitude, myJsArray[1].latitude],
                    [myJsArray[1].longitude, myJsArray[1].latitude],
                    [myJsArray[0].longitude, myJsArray[0].latitude]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
});
map.addLayer({
        'id': 'france',
        'type': 'line',
        'source': 'france',
          "layout": {
            "line-cap": "round",
            "line-join": "round",
          },
          "paint": {
            "line-color": "#D20C0C",
            "line-dasharray": [0.2, 2],
            "line-width": 2
          }
    });
};

});
```